# Is Molarity constant?

Tags: concentration, molecules

My friend and I were debating about if Molarity is constant in a disolution if this one changes volume due to evaporation.

There was this problem that stated that 125 [mL] of sodyum chloride 0.122 [M] evaporates over time and final volume becomes 113 [mL]

I say Molarity keeps being constant, he says no because volume changes.

What do you think?

Comment: $c_1=n/V_1;$ $c_2=n/V_2.$ What do *you* think the relation between $c_1$ and $c_2$ is when $V_1>V_2?$ Also, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_concentration).

Comment: If you knew what exactly molarity is, there would be no debate. As you did not, why did you not rather search it up, instead of asking? It would be much faster.  //  Do people obtain salt by evaporation of seawater, or are they liers ? Does have saturated NaCl solution the same molarity as e.g. 0.1 M NaCl solution ?

Comment: Presumably this is an aqueous solution. So more fundamental than andselisk's question: (1) Does water evaporate from a sodium chloride solution?  (2) Does sodium chloride evaporate from a sodium chloride solution?

Comment: Interestingly, I was reading someone's thesis on corrosion yesterday and airborne salinity is indeed a problem near coastal areas, so in one sense sodium chloride can also be lost in the air too!

Comment: @M.Farooq But it s rather dynamic separation of solution into aerosol, eventually evaporated later. I have head you need on some island to work with tap water ventils/regulators every 2 weeks, otherwise they get "frozen" due salt and you cannot turn them anymore.

Comment: @Poutnik, You are right. The aerosol is formed first.

Comment: Do you have any idea of concentration in real life? This is a surprising question. If you read molarity M as moles number then nothing change. But it is not. What is constant is n. M = n / V

Answer (score 1):

As [molarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_concentration) is defined as the ratio of molar amount of the dissolved solute and solution volume:

$$c=\frac nV$$

molarity increases when solvent ( like water ) evaporates.

Molarity can be considered constant only in context of later refilling the evaporated solvent and mixing the solution. Then molarity returns to the original value. It assumes the solute ( like sodium chloride ) content is constant, not undergoing any reaction.